# Intel T5600 to upgrade T5250

Tags: cpu, upgrade, intel-core2

I want to upgrade my laptop which has [T5250](http://ark.intel.com/products/30786/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T5250-%282M-Cache-1_50-GHz-667-MHz-FSB%29) CPU with a [T5600](http://ark.intel.com/products/27254/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T5600-%282M-Cache-1_83-GHz-667-MHz-FSB%29) CPU to support virtualization. I ordered T5600 on ebay, but it didn't fit. It says T5250 supports PPGA478 socket, so I assume that is what I have. T5600 says supports "PBGA479, PPGA478".

Since T5600 didn't fit as a replacement, I assume it means there are 2 models of T5600, one supports PBGA479, another one supports PPGA478, and not like I thought - one CPU supports both. Is that a correct statement?

Does anybody know if it's even possible to do such an upgrade, or I'm wasting time?

**UPDATE**: I found a [cheaper and better upgrade](http://blog.galets.net/2012/07/upgrade-cpu-on-lenovo-y410-enable.html) for my laptop: [T7250](http://ark.intel.com/products/31728/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7250-%282M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Same inside guts with different exterior packaging.
The [intel spec page lists](http://ark.intel.com/products/27254?wapkw=t5600) the CPU with different part numbers for each socket type.
And [this wikipedia page explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_479) a bit of the reason for how the 479 pin socket arrived on the same CPU platform.

Comment: The part number indicates it is [SL9U3](http://vvcap.net/db/75uZFS3F6vkeHiQtxKuA.htp), shich should also be [PPGA478 socket](http://vvcap.net/db/Ze0Cmlp6YgF1L1RHMBxd.htp), but nevertheless it doesn't match [mine](http://vvcap.net/db/gQHPxyH1RU3EVhEteNnm.htp). Any ideas why?..

Comment: Yes, from that chart, it looks like the SL9U7 would be the 479 pin version, and that the SL9U3 is the 478 pin. Is it possible one pin is slightly bent? The T5250 looks like it only comes in 478 pins, so your socket must need that type. The difference between 478/479 is that one extra pin. The 479 wikipedia page shows a closeup of the pins for both 478/479. Which looks like your cpu and socket? And sanity check - the cpu is aligned correctly? (sorry, had to ask).

Comment: why are you saying SL9U7? I thought both photo and my screenshot clearly indicate it is SL9U3

Comment: I agree with you. In this thread, only 478 and 479 sockets were mentioned. I was reiterating the intel chart, that the 479 pin version had a different part number. Clearly your cpu is SL9U3 which should be the 478 pin version. And the previous CPU is also supposed to be a 478 socket. So why doesn't the new CPU fit? Is the pin arrangement not match the socket, or are some pin slightly bent?

Comment: Yeah, seems to be different pin layout. [Here](http://vvcap.net/db/ew8LPr6MYG7juPEzuBNF.htp) is the CPU I originally had in laptop, and its [pin layout](http://vvcap.net/db/uT5oNg14TKgPCuhp6AK_.htp). Here is the [pin layout](http://vvcap.net/db/q5lY1JsUCi-Bntsv3XRy.htp) of the SL9U3 T5600 I bought.

Comment: Those photos helped this confusing issue. Apparently Intel uses the term "socket"  to refer both to the physical pin number and also the pin electronic layout. So the spec chart for T5600 shows it as physical pin 478 (and 479), but electronical ["Socket M"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_M) Their spec page shows T5250 is also physical socket 478, but electronic ["socket P"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_P). Sadly, sockets P and M can't be hacked to be converted (like the Asus 479 to 478 conversion kit did [CT-479]).